# How do I dynamically assign the size to an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, size, cardinality

So right now I have a class, called Set, in C++. In it, I have an integer called mCardinality, and an integer array called mElements. I want to be able to accept an integer in the constructor for mCardinality, then use this to assign a size to my integer array, is there any way to do this, or do I absolutely have to have a size for it right off the bat?
(I guess I could just make the size the maximum integer, then only use the cardinality for limiting the loops where I deal with the elements, but a neater solution would be preferable).

I did see on here that there may be a way to use std::vector to resize an array, will that work? And...how would that code look? And do vectors work just like arrays in C++ for everything else I want to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are these:

1. use std::vector or
2. use plain old array

With vector (recommended):

```
class YourSet {
public:
   YourSet(int size) : elements(size)
   {
   }
private:
   std::vector<int> elements;
};
```

With array (not really recommended because of possible exception safety issues):

```
class YourSet {
public:
   YourSet(int size)
   {
       elements = new int[size];
   }
   ~YourSet()
   {
        delete[] elements;
   }
private:
   int* elements;
   // no implementation to prevent shallow copying
   YourSet( const YourSet&);
   void operator=(const YourSet&);
};
```

Comment: I would prefer to use just the array. How would I do that?

Comment: @Taylor Matyasz: I included that, but really `vector` is better.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` will work for your purposes.

```
#include <vector>

class Set
{
  Set(int len)
   : mElements(len)
  {
  }

  void do_smth()
  {
    size_t vector_len = mElements.size();

    int index = 0;
    int element = mElements[index];
  }


  std::vector<int> mElements;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector holds pointer, and when it`s needed reallocate memory.

```
T* new_ptr = new T[new_size];
std::copy(ptr, ptr + size, new_ptr);
delete[] ptr;
ptr = new_ptr;
size = new_size;
```

It is simple example. Vector uses allocator, but at fact something like this.

Answer (score 1):

GO for a vector. It will resize itself automatically when you add or remove items from it, and you can specify the size of it also if needed.

```
 vector<myClass> m_vClasses;
 myClass myNewObject;
 m_Classes.push_back(myNewObject); // Vector resized when you add new element
```

You won't need to worry about memory or other issues (unless myClass is a pointer that points to dynamically allocated memory) assuming that your `myClass` destructor correctly frees any memory that the class allocates. The vector will deal with the resizing for you automatically.